# Excel VBA/Formula to search Column

Tags: excel, vba, search

I need to search a column for 5-9 digit ID's that follow the term `^v_cusip=` and are separated by commas. From first glance it seemed that the ID's were followed by `^v_sort_order` so I tried:

```
=MID(A2,FIND("^v_cusip=",A2)+9,(FIND("^v_sort_order=",A2)-(FIND("^v_cusip=",A2)+9)))
```

However, what follows `^v_cusip=` varies. Is there another formula or a VBA code I can use to search the rows? I cannot repeatedly use MID/FIND as there are thousands of rows with numerous variations of what can follow `^v_cusip=`.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at this? What you want is regex. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=LEFT(RIGHT(A2;LEN(A2)-FIND("^v_cusip=";A2)-8);FIND("^";RIGHT(A2;LEN(A2)-FIND("^v_cusip=";A2)-8))-1)
```

This will show only the part between ^v_cusip= and the next ^ character.
You can further split the string by comma.

Answer (score 0):

What does the rest of cell details look like? Is there only '=' sign in each row? If so, perhaps you could do a text to columns and use the '=' sign as the delimiter.

Once it's split should put the ID in a predictable column.

Comment: There is always a '^' at the end of the list of ID's but once again the cells contain many '^'